# How mobile printer that work alone and with WIFI for POS app?

Tags: iphone, printing, mobile, point-of-sale

I'm hunting for a mobile POS printer for use in a mobile point-of-sale application ([BestSeller](http://www.bestsellerapp.com)). The requeriments is that must work independent of anything except the mobile device. So the solution is only: Printer + iPhone.

I have a early question on this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558238/is-possible-send-print-commands-by-wifi-to-pos-mobile-printer) but with not answers.

The idea is that the printer work as their own server and I can send print commands to make tickets and that stuff.

The salesman work outside the company,and have not ascces to internet or other facilities.

I found this:

http://www.barcodegiant.com/epson/mobilink.htm

and

http://www.barcodegiant.com/zebra/mz220.htm

but is not clear to me if will work as I imagine. And also, I don't find any how to in how make the programing...

Answer (score 0):

You should probably just send your salesmen with laptops and printers as that solution is easy and well supported. I don't know of any solutions currently that would allow you to connect an iPhone directly to a printer or to print to a printer with wifi. Printing solutions currently available require some sort of desktop or server app counterpart to facilitate the actual printing.

Comment: ????????????

Exist a large number of salesman where is more acceptable the use of a small mobile device. And in this case, represent 100% customer base!

According to the sales material, this would work as described, but, I'm looking for someone with actual experience on this...